# ssh-copy-id not working on specific server

Tags: ssh, sshd, ssh-keys

I have a server running Ubuntu. I'm not able to grant access to any client using ssh-copy-id:

This is part of the sshd_config file in the server

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
```

And this is the output when I try to connect via ssh:

```
juan@utils:~/remote-backups$ ssh -v manolo
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/juan/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/juan/.ssh/config line 7: Applying options for manolo
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Hostname has changed; re-reading configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/juan/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to [ip] [[ip]] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/juan/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/juan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/juan/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/juan/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/juan/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/juan/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/juan/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/juan/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 0b:d6:6c:c5:98:f2:c5:40:52:ce:b8:90:ee:7f:81:e9
debug1: Host '[ip]' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/juan/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/juan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/juan/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/juan/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/juan/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
juan@[ip]'s password:
```

I've tried to connect via several clients, so I suspect that the issue is on the server part. I've also restarted ssh service in the server.

Other connections are working on my local machine, so file permissions might be OK

File permissions in the server:

/home/juan/.ssh

```
drwx------ 2 juan juan 4.0K Oct 24 08:04 .ssh

-rw------- 1 juan juan 9.4K Dec 23 09:31 authorized_keys
```

Comment: check permissions on server!

Comment: Did you make sure that the directory containing the keys, on the server, has permissions 700 (= rwx------) and that the file authorized_keys, within it, has permissions 600 (= rw-------)?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae  yes, updated topic with that info

Comment: Do you have root access to the server?

Comment: yes @MariusMatutiae, it's an Ubuntu VPS, I'm the owner

Comment: Then the easiest thing is to stop the sshd daemon on the server, start it manually, then try to connect and see the error messages spewed out on the screen. You can use a command like: `service sshd stop; /usr/sbin/sshd -dD ; service sshd start`, as sudo, all in one line. The error messages will be more meaningful.